# Heroku Logs Not Loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, logging, deployment

In my Heroku dashboard or on my command, when I try to open my logs i get a 503 Service Unavailable and I can't file a support ticket because I am using a free account. Does anyone know why this would be happening? The Heroku status monitor also says that Heroku services are all good https://status.heroku.com/. My app is also currently running and it does not seem to be affected. I am pretty sure this is an issue with Heroku but I can't get any support due to being a free account.

Comment: Did you try `heroku logs -t` so you can see the log 'tail'?

Comment: An incident has been added to their status site: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1633